# JavaScript Event is not working with getElementById

Tags: javascript, image, function, events

I have a problem with JS Events. I placed an image on my website and with the help of JS when one would click the image, the `src` attribute would be set to find another image. But nothing happens!

#### CODE

```
<img id="img" src="Login_img1.jpg" width="425" height="219" alt="Hey" onclick="img()">
```

Now the JS:

```
function img(){document.getElementById("img").src = "Login_img2.jpg"}
```

Comment: Open up your debug console and tell us which error you see.

Comment: Please do not edit new questions into existing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't name your function `img()`. It works fine when you use something that's not equivalent to a global object.

Comment: [img is NOT a reserved word!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)

Comment: `img` isn't a "reserved word".  It's the ID of an element.  Some browsers turn IDs into global variables.

Comment: Your first question was answered. This is now a different question and should be posted as a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), and ditch the HTML `onclick` attribute:

```
var img = document.getElementById('img');
img.onclick = function(){
    img.src = "Login_img2.jpg";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This could simple be done using `this` keyword removing the unnecessary search for the element.

```
<img id="img" src="Login_img1.jpg" width="425" height="219" alt="Hey" onclick="change_img(this)">
```

```
function change_img(img){
   img.src = "Login_img2.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be do to the fact that you named both your function `img` and the id of your element `img`.

Browsers will actually use ID's as global variables. So, simply by creating an element with an id of `img` you've essentially created `window.img`.

It'd be bettr to rename your function to something like `swapImg` and use `this` and the JavaScript `onclick` method instead of having your `onclick` in the markup as well as wrapping your code in an IIFE to avoid leaking variables into the global `window` object...

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('img').onclick = swapImage;

    function swapImage() {
        this.src = 'Login_img2.jpg';
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already got solution to your question. Just want to point out that you may do it using event listeners too.

```
var oImg = document.getElementById('myImg');
oImg.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.setAttribute('src', 'Login_img2.jpg');
}, false);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get anything of what you wrote there. I'm a beginner

Comment: Could you please answer to the update of the question? Thank you!